# How can I satisfy the `Sum<T>` trait requirement for f32?

Tags: generics, rust, iterator, traits

I have the following trait that I am trying to implement:

```
pub trait CentralMoment<Output = f32>
where
    Output: Copy,
{
    fn mean(&self) -> Output;
}

impl<T> CentralMoment for [T] {
    fn mean(&self) -> f32 {
        let sum: f32 = self.iter().sum();
        sum / self.len() as f32
    }
}
```

My issue is with the line `let sum: f32 = self.iter().sum()`. The compiler is telling me:

```
the trait bound `f32: Sum<&T>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:45:36
   |
45 |         let sum: f32 = self.iter().sum();
   |                                    ^^^ the trait `Sum<&T>` is not implemented for `f32`
   |
help: consider extending the `where` bound, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
   |
42 |     T: Copy, f32: Sum<&T>
```

but even when I try include `f32: Sum<&T>` I still get the same error.
What am I doing wrong here and how can I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance, and please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arithmetic with generics is tricky. Getting all of the constraints and types right is like a game of whack-a-mole. Every time you fix an error another is going to pop up. I don't want to jump straight to the answer; it's better if we go through each of the steps one-by-one. That said, if you just want to see the solution it's at the bottom.

Let's start whacking.

#### 1. Copy the numbers

Take a look at the [implementors for `Sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Sum.html#implementors). They look like this:

```
impl Sum<f32> for f32
impl Sum<f64> for f64
impl Sum<i8> for i8
impl Sum<i16> for i16
impl Sum<i32> for i32
...
```

And so on.

The general pattern is obvious:

```
impl Sum<T> for T
```

None of them match your code because it's apparently trying to use `Sum<&T>`. We need to get rid of the references so `Sum<&T>` can be `Sum<T>`.

Where are the references coming from? `iter()` iterates over item references. It does this to avoid modifying the collection or its items.

We could use `into_iter()` to iterate over the items directly. Let's not, though. `into_iter()` converts a collection *into* an iterator. Converts... as in destroys. It moves all the items and consumes the collection in the process. Yikes!

Instead, let's copy the items with [`copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied):

> This is useful when you have an iterator over `&T`, but you need an iterator over `T`.

```
let sum: f32 = self.iter().copied().sum();
```

We'll also need a `T: Copy` constraint:

```
impl<T> CentralMoment for [T]
where
    T: Copy,
```

This changes the error to:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `f32: Sum<T>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:13:45
   |
13 |         let sum: f32 = self.iter().copied().sum();
   |                                             ^^^ the trait `Sum<T>` is not implemented for `f32`
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=38d70fe8a66f552e839495978ece1c52)</sup>

#### 2. Result of summing is `T`

When you sum up a bunch of `i32`s you're going to get an `i32`. When you sum a bunch of `f64`s you're going to get an `f64`. This code says the result of `sum()` will be an `f32`, but really to be properly generic you should call it a `T`.

```
let sum: T = self.iter().copied().sum();
```

Now the error is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: Sum` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:13:43
   |
13 |         let sum: T = self.iter().copied().sum();
   |                                           ^^^ the trait `Sum` is not implemented for `T`
```

#### 3. `T` must be summable

We can fix that requiring that `T: Sum`:

```
where
    T: Copy + Sum,
```

Now we get:

```
error[E0369]: cannot divide `T` by `f32`
  --> src/lib.rs:16:13
   |
16 |         sum / self.len() as f32
   |         --- ^ ----------------- f32
   |         |
   |         T
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bf4bcc623ae9c74ab40c7df373c9a8c7)</sup>

#### 4. `T` must be divisible by `f32`

We're close, right? Let's require that `T` be divisible by `f32`s:

```
where
    T: Copy + Sum + Div<f32>,
```

Are you happy, compiler?

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:17:9
   |
15 |     fn mean(&self) -> f32 {
   |                       --- expected `f32` because of return type
16 |         let sum: T = self.iter().copied().sum();
17 |         sum / self.len() as f32
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `f32`, found associated type
   |
   = note:         expected type `f32`
           found associated type `<T as Div<f32>>::Output`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<T as Div<f32>>::Output` to `f32`
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84fee41fe4a59c4c36f09caa86fdc872)</sup>

No, of course not. Fine, fine, now what?

#### 5. Division must return an `f32`

Well, we've required that `T` be divisible by `f32`. We haven't told it what type the result would be, though. It's not a given that operand types and result types are the same. They could be different. Rust is oh-so-flexible.

We need to put a constraint on the `::Output` of the operation. Let's require that the output also be an `f32`:

```
where
    T: Copy + Sum + Div<f32, Output = f32>,
```

Result:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
 Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.91s
```

Hallelujah! The princess is not in another castle.

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0c44d001d0fe1883a2ae426caf748c3c)</sup>

## Solution

```
use std::iter::Sum;
use std::ops::Div;

pub trait CentralMoment<Output = f32>
where
    Output: Copy,
{
    fn mean(&self) -> Output;
}

impl<T> CentralMoment for [T]
where
    T: Copy + Sum + Div<f32, Output = f32>,
{
    fn mean(&self) -> f32 {
        let sum: T = self.iter().copied().sum();
        sum / self.len() as f32
    }
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0c44d001d0fe1883a2ae426caf748c3c)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Not only was this the solution I was looking for, but thank you for the concise explanation. Playing whack-a-mole was exactly what I was doing with this. I often find myself in this situation with Rust (especially with generics).

Comment: Note that the only standard library type that is `Div<f32, Output = f32>` is `f32, so unless you implement that trait for a custom type the impl won't be actually generic.

Comment: _Fantastic_ answer